# Mass cell naming and hyperlinking in excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have 4 columns in **excel sheet 1** which contain a mixture of Source and Destination ports and IPs. I.E: for source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port I may have:

10.1.1.1, any, 10.2.2.2, 443.

OR

SUBNET_GROUP, any, OTHER_GROUP, 80.

It works with specific IPs, or group names. In **excel sheet 2**, I have the groups defined. Such as:

SUBNET_GROUP

192.168.0.1

192.168.0.2

192.168.0.3

I would like to create a hyperlink so that clicking on SUBNET_GROUP in **excel sheet 1** takes me to SUBNET_GROUP in **excel sheet 2** but there are thousands of entries and hundreds of groups.

The thing is, there are actually about 4 sets of **excel sheet 1** and **excel sheet 2**.

I was thinking one solution would be to name the groups in **excel sheet 2** something like env1_cellcontents so the name would be like env1_SUBNET_GROUP in **excel sheet 2** and in **excel sheet 1** I could link SUBNET_GROUP to env1_SUBNET_GROUP. The pair of sheet 3/4 could use env2_SUBNET_GROUP when it comes up, as well. Though perhaps simply referring to another sheet instead of naming would make more sense here.

I have found a lot of links on re-doing hyperlinks, but not on actually creating them. Is there a more efficient way to do this than mass-naming and mass-linking based on cell content? How would I go about the mass naming and creating hyperlinks? The other issue is that some cells are specific IPs and do not need to be linked.

Thanks,

Comment: Read up on string / variable concatenation in VBA

Comment: You could also record a macro while you are creating an hyperlink manually and then modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Are there any good resources for this? I am not overly familiar with VBA but I think I can figure it out. (in reference to mehow) I will look into macros too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't focus on hyperlinks. Instead use Worksheet_SelectionChange to see if user clicks on a single cell in column A, then see what the content is, and based on that take them to the other sheet and appropriate cell. You can check to see if one cell in column A is selected like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Row = Target.Cells.Row
    Col = Target.Cells.Column
    If Col = 1 And And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

      'enter the rest of code here, such as selecting the cell on sheet2 that corresponds to what user selected on sheet 1
      Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
      Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False
      Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If


End Sub
```